# Is there a state that needs to be reset in between shaders

Tags: c#, xna, shader, xna-4.0

I am just starting out with shaders using XNA and I ran into some behavoir I didn't understand almost immediately.

I created a simple scene with a textured box and some ground for it to sit on, composed of a single textured quad using a repeating texture (so my texture coordinates where from 0,0 to 10,10 to make it repeat 10 times). Initially both of these used the BasicEffect class.

I then followed a tutorial to create my first shader and used it for the cube - nothing more then a shader that returns the color of the texture at the coordinate coordinate, giving me the same textured cube as I had before.

However something strange happened - suddenly the ground was mostly a solid color with 2 blurry edges and one instance of the proper texture in the corner. The texture was no longer repeating. I changed the order in which I drew the cube and the ground to no effect, only commenting out the cube solved things.

Then I looked in my shader code, mostly just copied from the tutorial, and saw that it specified Clamp for AddressU and AddressV. Changing that to Wrap fixed everything, but still leaves me with a question - why was the texture wrapping logic of one shader affecting the basic shader? Is this a normal behavoir, is there some kind of state saving I need to do, or does this indicate I might have another bug in my code?

```
groundEffect.View = camera1.View; // BasicEffect
groundEffect.Projection = projection;
groundEffect.World = Matrix.CreateTranslation(0, -1.5f, 0);
groundEffect.TextureEnabled = true;
groundEffect.Texture = groundTexture;
GraphicsDevice.Indices = groundIndexBuffer;
GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(groundVertexBuffer);
foreach (EffectPass pass in groundEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
{
    pass.Apply();
    GraphicsDevice.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0, groundVertexBuffer.VertexCount, 0, groundIndexBuffer.IndexCount / 3); 
}


shaderEffect.Parameters["View"].SetValue(camera1.View);
shaderEffect.Parameters["Projection"].SetValue(projection);
shaderEffect.Parameters["World"].SetValue(modelPosition);
shaderEffect.Parameters["ModelTexture"].SetValue(boxTexture);
GraphicsDevice.Indices = model.IndexBuffer;
GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(model.VertexBuffer);
foreach (EffectPass pass in shaderEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
{
    pass.Apply();
    GraphicsDevice.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0, model.VertexBuffer.VertexCount, 0, model.IndexBuffer.IndexCount / 3);    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The render state is controlled by four state objects:

```
GraphicsDevice.BlendState
GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState
GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[] // one for each sampler
```

Their introduction in XNA 4 is explained in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/02/state-objects-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx).

All state changes go through these variables OR can be set in a `.fx` file.

IIRC, XNA's built-in `Effect` objects don't set state using either method - although `SpriteBatch` does.

I can't say for sure what is setting the state in your case, from the code you've provided. Normally I would guess that `SpriteBatch` is the culprit ([see this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/06/18/spritebatch-and-renderstates-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx)) - as this comes up a lot. But maybe it's something in your `shaderEffect`.

In any case, it's perfectly reasonable to simply set the states you want before rendering. Here's the typical states for 3D rendering:

```
GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise;
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearWrap;
```